# Sitecore homepage not showing....admin page half showing instead

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a site in Sitecore.  I have pushed this site to a new server with a new domain name.  The domain name is listed in the site/hostname node of the .config file.  When I visit the URL root (where the site should be - and is, on every other environment), though, what I see is (what looks like) the topmost banner of the Sitecore login page (the page I'd see if I went to /sitecore/login), and that's it.  No form to login to or anything like that.  I shouldn't be seeing this page at all, but that I'm seeing it only partly is even weirder. Any ideas as to why this would be would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Seems very strange... any errors in the log or windows event log? And have you copied all the files over?

Comment: Can you update your question with your `<site>` nodes form the config in the exact order they are listed?

Comment: Also this behavior can occur when you are having troubles with the authentication mode in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are seeing is just a Sitecore logo, it sounds like you need to do a publish to get your site transferred from the Master database to the Web database.

Try a full site publish, and see if that helps.  The default empty web database usually displays something similar to what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem wasn't Sitecore, exactly.  There was another Sitecore site on the same web server, and that site was configured to accept all unassigned requests.  The site I was deploying to was misconfigured in IIS, so when I was trying to hit it, I was actually hitting the other site, where my domain was not configured, leading to - I think - the kinds of publish/configure issues that Jay suggests.